# Bash not loading '.profile' in new session on Linux

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, bashrc, .bash-profile

I'm setting up a new Linux machine I got from our IT dept, and noticed `.profile` is not loaded when I start a new terminal session. The current shell is [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), though I changed it from the default [sh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) it came with. How do I make it load `.profile` on startup?

I access the shell via [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell): `ssh myusername@remotemachine`. I have administrator privileges on it.

Comment: Show us your the command you use to start your shell.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When Bash starts as an interactive login shell, one of the files it *may* process is `~/.profile`.

When it starts as an interactive non-login shell it doesn't. It processes `/etc/bash.bashrc` (if that file or a similar file is enabled in your version of Bash) and  `~/.bashrc`.

You could add the following to your `~/.bashrc` (but be careful of loops or values being changed inadvertently):

```
. $HOME/.profile
```

Comment: If you're going to have your .bashrc source your .profile (which i don't recommend) you should have some guard against double sourcing.  Set some guard variable or so

`[ -z "$SOME_VAR_SET_IN_PROFILE" ] && . ~/.profile`

Comment: Yeah, I don't really recommend it either.

Comment: A login shell will try ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login and ~/.profile in order and only open the first one it finds.

Comment: As others have said, this is NOT recommended, since the usual way is for profile and "friends" (.bash_profile) to source .bashrc, and not the other way.  It could be that your terminal program is NOT a login shell, but an interactive non-login shell.  Often there's a preference you can set -- make it a login shell to get .profile, .login and/or .bash_profile to execute.

Answer (score 19):

It kind of depends how you start your shell.  As others have said, a login shell will load your profile (it will look for .bash_profile first, then will try .profile).  If it finds one of these, it loads them.  A non-login shell (either interactive or non-interactive) will source .bashrc.

I'd suggest putting everything into .bashrc.  The .profile/.bashrc split was kind of arbitrary and made more sense in the old days of UNIX when tty wasn't just a device name and meant an actual TeleType.  It was meant to start certain things (like checking mail) on the 'main' login to a server, and just normal setup stuff for other shells.  In most Linuxes you will log in now, you're not really logging into a shell, as you're logging into some graphical interface (KDE, gnome, CDE 'shudder').  The "spawn login processes" is now taken care of by your session manager.  It's much less relevant now.

My suggestion:
Make your .profile consist of solely:

```
[ -f $HOME/.bashrc ] && . $HOME/.bashrc
```

as the first line of .bashrc, guard against weird stuff happening when running a bash script by jumping out early:

```
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
```

Comment: `.profile` should be kept bash agnostic. I suggest to configure `.bash_profile` to load `.profile` and then load `.bashrc`. put only bash agnostic stuff in `.profile`, like `PATH` and the `LC_*` stuff. Put the rest in `.bashrc`.

Comment: @Rich Homolka Why is [ -f $HOME/.bashrc ] twice in your command? How is the command you posted different from just '. $HOME/.bashrc' ?

Comment: Protip: Don't put anything in your .bashrc that writes to stdout or stderr, as that can break non-interactive clients for things such as SCP.  Things with output (for example, I like to be greeted with a fortune cookie and uptime) should only go in .profile / .bash_profile

Comment: @Lotharyx true. We had a standard-ish kshrc that exported to stdout, broke out Xserver (hummingbird exceed)