# Linux: bashrc. How to load bashrc content from another file?

Tags: linux, bash, bashrc

I occasionally have to re-install operating systems on the various linux machines which I manage. Every time I do this, I have to copy the `.bashrc` file to a USB drive before wiping the old system, and then put it back after I've installed a new system. (And perhaps edit it if something is no longer compatiable.)

This is annoying, and I usually stick to one version of a Linux OS and install it on most of my machines, so I've been trying to store my `.bashrc` content in a new file inside my Dropbox folder.

For example, I have put `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "` in a file named `mybash` inside my Dropbox folder.

What do I need to put inside my `.bashrc` file to "load all the stuff from the `mybash` file"?

I tried this, but it didn't seem to work?

```
# Load bash custom files
if [ -f /home/user/Dropbox/mybash ]
then
    . /home/user/Dropbox/mybash
fi
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. Why not create a git repository and host on github. And when you want it just do a git clone.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus Good idea could also do this - Dropbox was just a quick easy way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem using some info found [here](http://www.rebrik.info/blog/?p=74).

Menu -> Edit -> Preferences -> General -> Tick the box: run as login shell

Thanks to AnythingIsFine for pointing me in the right direction.

This is an XFCE Terminal specific solution.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that the user which is sourcing the .bashrc file has permsission to read from:

> . /home/user/Dropbox/mybash

Users can't read from one another's home dirs, unless specifically configured to do so.

The real reason might be because you are missing your

```
~/.bash_profile
```

file which sources your

```
~/.bashrc
```

where you finally instructed to source your `mybash` file.

You should add your code to the:

```
~/.bash_profile
```

instead.

Comment: I am the same user so my guess would be yes?

Comment: I edited my comment to show the cause I suspect.

Comment: I have no `.bash_profile` file on my system. What am I supposed to put in it?

Comment: List all the files from /home (including hidden files) and   see which one is sourcing ".bashrc". It may be simply named ".profile" as well.

Comment: It seems to be `.profile`. What should I put in this file to load contents from another?

Comment: Same as what you put in your original question, the if condition and the source of "mybash", thr login again and check your history log for timestamp

Comment: Why does "nesting" not work? eg; One file loads another which loads another?

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working either way...

Comment: Are you using "su - user" to login ?

Comment: No I login using xfce4? Sorry not sure if I understand the question?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the XFCE terminal you use to login, but please login as a different user and then issue the "su - <user>" to see if your file is sourced.

Comment: Did that no difference

Comment: Are you sure you are using "bash" as a login shell ? please run this command "echo $SHELL"

Comment: It's definitely bash /bin/bash

Comment: Then, it might be because of your login terminal, XFCE4. Take a look at the below 2 links to see if it helps...[Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566399/why-isnt-profile-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal)    or    [Unix](https://superuser.com/questions/176404/bash-not-loading-profile-in-new-session-on-linux)